# Deserializing JSON strings which have quotes and apostrophes in them

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, deserialization

So, I have an JSON object where one of the string members have characters like quotes(") and apostrophes(') in them.

This JSON object is returned by a third party API (which I have no control over). This is how I invoke this API:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var data = new NameValueCollection();              
var result = client.UploadValues(url, data);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(result);
```

So, when I try to deserialise this string like so:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
MyClass obj= serializer.ReadObject(ms) as MyClass;
ms.Close();
```

I get an error that says "{"Encountered unexpected character '&'."}".

When I read the byte array into a string using the following code, I see that 
the ampersand and apostrophe characters are encoded as '&#039' and '& quot ;'.

```
MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream(result);
ms2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms2);
string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

So it looks like the Deserializer does not like the ampersand characters in the JSON string. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried html decoding the response? If it's being returned from a get request you can get this sort of behaviour.

Comment: Yes, it just decodes the encoded quote character to an actual quote and that breaks the JSON too. Damn if you do...

Answer (score 0):

http://json.org/
because is not the right way to serialize amperstands and double quotes... If you have no control over that i suggest you to html decode and then an addslashes... Or a find and replace...